How to use coil with web view for caching image
I am in transition to replacing Glide with Coil.
In Glide, there is an easy option to Cache web view images to load images faster. Is the same available for Coil?
The main issue I am facing in Coil is how to return the WebResourceResponse when saving web view images in cache
Following is how I use Glide while compressing the bitmap.
 override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                 view: WebView?,
                 request: WebResourceRequest?
             ): WebResourceResponse? {
                 try {
                     val url = request!!.url.toString()
                     if (url.lowercase().contains(".jpg") || url.lowercase().contains(".jpeg")) {
                         val bitmap =
                             Glide.with(webView).asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                 .load(url).submit().get()
                         return WebResourceResponse(
                             "image/jpg",
                             "UTF-8",
                             getBitmapInputStream(bitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                         )
                     } else if (url.lowercase().contains(".png")) {
                         val bitmap =
                             Glide.with(webView).asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                 .load(url).submit().get()
                         return WebResourceResponse(
                             "image/jpg",
                             "UTF-8",
                             getBitmapInputStream(bitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
                         )
                     } else {
                         return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
                     }
                 } catch (e: Exception) {
                     return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
                 }
             }
        }
    }



private fun getBitmapInputStream(bitmap: Bitmap, compressFormat: CompressFormat): InputStream {
    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(compressFormat, 80, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val bitmapData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    return ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapData)
}

I tried replacing the Gldie code with Colin using the following, but it's a suspend function and unable to return the data.
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(requireContext())
                           .data(url)
                           .build()
val drawable = requireActivity().imageLoader.execute(request).drawable?.toBitmap()

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Coil is for Compose.  Is that what you are trying to do?

No, I am adding Coil to my Kotlin code base not for Compose
